# WSO2 ESB - architecture for FIX

Tags: architecture, fix-protocol, wso2-esb

I am a beginner in ESB subject, with no expieriance in that subject at all.

I am about to create an application for Prop trading using WSO2 ESB (I like the thing they have implemented FIX server in it). However, in our company we need to separate external connections and Intranet using DMZ. What kind of archtecture should I use:

1. ESB installed both on Intranet and DMZ servers, connected between themselves using some kind of stream like online replication used in databases
2. ESB installed both on Intranet and DMZ servers, using JMS or other type of messaging to communicate
3. ESB installed only on the Intranet server and QuickFIX installed on the DMZ server

The architecture choosen should allow the Order Management System to be extremely quick, with no unnecessary latency.

Answer (score 0):

So the DMZ is basically a firewall that allows certain IP addresses and ports to communicate together, right? You need to talk to the guys who implement that about the best way to allow external FIX sessions through the DMZ. They can open certain IP and port for FIX connections.

Comment: As a matter of fact we have a solution you mentioned implemented in our company. As I always wanted to create such a software myself I thought about finding a quicker way to do that. But having no experiance in ESB at all I am not sure if I could do any better than FIX server located in DMZ and the rest in Intranet. Could WSO2 ESB act as a FIX server with all that incoming/outgoing flow or it is just able to translate messages from let's say JMS to FIX 4.2. Would sending messages from ESB to QuickFix using FIX protocol would quicken the flow at least a little bit?